# how to send data from server to specific client ID on button click in winForm SIgnalR

Tags: signalr

I'm using SignalR for two way communication between server and client , both Server and Clients are using Win application .

Server side i'm adding all connected client ID in DropDownlist and now  i want to do  Two thing .

1) I want select client ID from drop down list then send string to selected client on button click.

**my server side is here :**

```
private void buttonClient_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
         // here i want write code for send data to selected client .
          string Clientid = comboBoxClients.SelectedItem.ToString();

        }

public class MyHub : Hub
    {
 public void Send(string name, string message){ Clients.All.addMessage(name, message);}
    }
```

**My Client Side Code here :**

```
private void ButtonSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            HubProxy.Invoke("Send", UserName, TextBoxMessage.Text);
            TextBoxMessage.Text = String.Empty;
            TextBoxMessage.Focus();
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First Add global Object of IhubContext .

```
IHubContext context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<MyHub>();



private void buttonClient_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string Clientid = comboBoxClients.SelectedItem.ToString();
// sendOrders(string,string) this method should make on client side with same name  and here call like thats . 
            context.Clients.Client(Clientid).sendOrders("Name","Message Server to you"); 

        }
```

**// My Client Side Code here :**
//Creates and connects the hub connection and hub proxy and call Method name SendOrders.
//display message in consolewindow

```
HubProxy.On<string, string>("sendOrders", (name, myString) =>
             this.Invoke((Action)(() =>
                    RichTextBoxConsole.AppendText(String.Format("{0}: {1}" + Environment.NewLine, name, myString))
                ))
            );
```

I hope this help

Answer (score 2):

In signalr you can use the concept of [groups](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/working-with-groups) since state is missing by default. To send messages to a specific client you can [map users to connections](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/mapping-users-to-connections)

Comment: yes i knew concept of groups . its seem difficult to  implement in small demo. i just needed to make a test demo .

Comment: Hi Tariq. Groups are easy to use, but not very dynamic. A custom implementation where you map users to connections is what I would use. Do note that you will need win8+ and .NET 4.5 to get websockets since you use desktop clients http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/supported-platforms.